# Where to start with building a blotter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, grid

I need to build a blotter using csharp and WPF. Basically, like an excel sheet but would have the capability of customizing backgrounds of each cell or setting the value of each cell. But not sure where to start. 
If anybody build blotters in csharp or WPF, a few pointers on where to get started would be great. If you can suggest some good open source blotters that I can copy and enhance, that would also be great.

I cannot use standard data grids as they lack many of the capabilities I am looking for.

I know windows forms and applications related to that which have standard controls but to create cells that are editable/customizable like excel, not sure where to start....

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think you've provided enough information.  What standard data grids did you try, and what capabilities did they fail to provide?  Without that information, you're going to continue to get vague answers.

Comment: You should also assume that many people don't know what a blotter is.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Adaptable Blotter (www.adaptableblotter.com).
It includes all the functionality that you seek and works with a number of different WPF grid controls, both vendor and open source.  There is a single set of screens giving you advanced search, flashing cells, bulk editing etc but with individual implementations for each underlying grid.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a UniformGrid to create the Grid. You can put Textboxes or even more advanced UserControls into the cells.